# Python - How to index elements in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, google-api, youtube, youtube-api

Im coding for a youtube API, now trying to get a channel's playlist of uploaded videos's ID.
I got this code:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

api_key = *im not showing this*
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

channel_id = 'UCLtX-6aeUi-Av6ocKcDwQYA'
request = youtube.channels().list(id=channel_id,
                                  part='contentDetails')
res = request.execute()
print(res['items'])
```

I get the following result:

```
[
   {
      "kind":"youtube#channel",
      "etag":"\"ksCrgYQhtFrXgbHAhi9Fo5t0C2I/OqBagYqEiOTpJzaoMetqts7kYwM\"",
      "id":"UCLtX-6aeUi-Av6ocKcDwQYA",
      "contentDetails":{
         "relatedPlaylists":{
            "uploads":"UULtX-6aeUi-Av6ocKcDwQYA",
            "watchHistory":"HL",
            "watchLater":"WL"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Now, obviously I would have to get that uploads from relatedPlaylists from contentDetails.
Since all that result is like a list with one element, and there are dictionaries inside, I can't do further than res['items']
(I tried res['items']['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'] but that gives me the following error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`)
I know this must be as simple as it looks but I can't find a way to do that. I was thinking of using a for loop to loop through res['items'] but I don't think that would be a good solution. Maybe I'm wrong though
I hope someone can help
Thank you :)

Comment: I think a loop *would* be a good solution :) `for item in res['items']: ...` now each item is an easily indexable dict. It also guarantees handling of every item in the response, without making assumptions regarding their count.

Comment: Alright. Nonetheless, it doesn't have a lot of elements and shouldn't be slow

Comment: always add the language tag first